# how to setup sites framework in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-sites

I am trying to setup multiple sites from a single project in django.  I was trying to set this up following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/  but there is no mention of setup only how to use the sites framework once implemented.

I have implmented sites before and I added sites to my installed apps like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

)
```

I tried to issue the command: python manage.py makemigrations but it says:

> No Changes detected

I'm using django 1.8 , does the sites framework setup still create a table called django_site ?

How do I do the initial setup to have this table created?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I needed to just migrate instead of make migrate like this:

```
python manage.py migrate
```